# How to define a fitness function to make sure the best fitness value is 'close to 9' in genetic algorithm

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms, fitness-functions

I am learning about genetic algorithms (GA), but I encountered a question about the definition of the fitness function used in GA.

I understand that the fitness function should return a scalar value (e.g. to make sure to return the maximum value for a given individual).

For example, if one wanted to optimize a small molecule $logP$ (to ensure that the returned $logP$ has the maximum values), one can define the fitness value thusly: $J(m) = logP$, and then use GA to optimize the $logP$.

But my question is that I want to make sure that the $logP$ has a value close to 9 (rather than the larger the better), the more closer to 9 the better.

In this case how can I define the fitness function used in GA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use this one: 1 / abs(logP - 9) as the fitness function. Also considering denominator is zero the corner case. If abs(logP - 9) = 0, then one can set it as very small number like 0.0000000001.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).